# Beginner help with raised cosine graph of impulse in Matlab

Tags: fft, matlab, cosine

Hi I'm looked to graph a Raised Cosine Bell Curve according to ones similar presented in the linked article. I have no experience with MatLab, and have found little luck scowering this and other sites along with the paper cited.

I have all of the data gathered along with the values of A, B1, and C1 for input in the raised cosine function. The data collected is standard motion capture data; time, frame #, position, and I've calculated angular/linear velocity for each joint marker recorded.  However, how do I put this onto Matlab so that  can get the impulse waveforms similar to the one on the article. I have a class project that is due soon and my overconfidence about Matlab use clearly has put me in a hole. Any help with code would be awesome, thank you!

x = time, y = Force(n)

Article: https://journals.biologists.com/jeb/article/220/2/247/18645/A-general-relationship-links-gait-mechanics-and

equation:

[image]

Comment: What are your values for $A$, $B$ and $C$?
I'm guessing your problem is you don't know how to define the time vector $t$.
Try something like `t = 0:0.01:0.5`

Comment: Also, what is "*x = time, y = Force(n)*" doing here?
Please post what you've tried already.